# Django - Model id in Detail View URL, 1st id not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a model, `Position`, which I have created a detail view to view each individual position.

views.py

```
def position_detail_view(request, id=None):

    position = get_object_or_404(Position, id=id)

    context= {
        'object': position,
    }

    return render(request, 'positions/position_detail.html', context)
```

positions/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import position_list_view, position_detail_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', position_list_view),
    path('<int:id>', position_detail_view, name='detail')
]
```

When I go to http://localhost:8000/apply/1/, where the id=1, I get a Page Not Found 404 Error. However, with any other id, the page loads just fine. Any ideas on why the first id in the model gives a 404 error?

> Edit 1: Traceback Error
>
> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/apply/1/ Using the URLconf defined in
>   bta_website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ [name='home'] apply/application/ apply/ apply/ 
>   [name='detail'] The current path, apply/1/, didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

Comment: are you sure object with id 1 exists in database?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Yes, I just checked the database and the admin to confirm that there is an object with id=1.

Comment: add your full error traceback

Comment: Now in the post.

Comment: change url path to `path('/<int:id>/', position_detail_view, name='detail')`

Comment: Now working, thank you! Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: ok add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `get_object_or_404` works like below.

```
get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs)
```

Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.
In your case,
your URL path is not properly configured.
Try to make changes this:

```
path('/<int:id>/', position_detail_view, name='detail')
```